# Binance API doesn't display EUR price pair

Tags: vb.net, binance-api-client

Recently trying to figure it out why "**OOKIDAO**" doesn't show up as pair when calling binance api url.

For example BTC EUR price or other crypto shows up this URL:

`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCEUR`

But I need `OOKIDAO` to show with `EUR` pair so this URL doesn't work: `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=OOKIEUR`

I tried also `OOKIDAO` or '`_`' but no success.
However pairing with USDT works but I need EUR.

thanks for advice since I didnt found it at all in github docs.

Comment: Just leaving out the symbol will list all available symbols `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price`, easier to look for a potential symbol in a complete list.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thank you but there is not EUR pair so sad I have found anyways other free api but it is limited to 10 calls per sec https://syncwith.com/api/coingecko/get/api-v3-coins-id

Answer (score 0):

Binance doesn't not have the pair OOKI / EUR that's why you can't find the working API.
The only pairs listed on Binance for OOKI are USDT, BUSD, BNB, ETH.

Comment: well I know but was thing about to get some help how to do without htmlelements scraping

Comment: If you know it why you are asking why Binance API doesn't display EUR price pair? It doesn't make any sense. You should also realize that between exchanges the prices are slightly different.